# Options Profit Calculation

Tags: options

If I buy PLTR at a $40 call, for $7.55 price per share, and I buy 5 contracts. The current stock price is $32.59.

Robinhood says the break-even price is $47.55.

How much money do I make if the price goes up to $50 before my option expiry date? How much if the price goes up to $60? How do I calculate this in general?

Answer (score 1):

The profit you make on an option (or anything) is the amount of money you receive minus the amount of money you pay. From your example, if the price goes up to $50 and you exercise the option, you'll be able to sell the stock for $50/share. You'll have paid $7.55 for the option plus the $40 strike for a total of $47.55. So if you subtract that from the $50 you can get by selling the stock, your profit is $2.45 per share (each contact is for 100 shares).

This formula is the general formula you'd apply to calculate your profit or loss:

Final stock price - (option price + strike price + fees).

If that value is positive, it signifies a profit. If it's negative, a loss. And the stock price that makes the formula come out to zero is the break-even price. Note, though, that you'll never lose more than the option price because if the stock price falls below the strike, you won't exercise the option.

Comment: Your answer is applicable to exercise or to expiration but it doesn't answer the OP's question of `How much money do I make if the price goes up to $50 before my option expiry date?`

Comment: @BobBaerker I took the question to be asking about holding to expiry since the price of the option is not directly related to that price of the underlying on its own without information about the expiry date.

Comment: Your answer is correct but... How you took the question has nothing to do with the OP's question about option value pre expiration.  In addition, in most cases, it makes sense to sell the option to close rather than exercise it unless either 1) you want to own the stock or 2) the bid is less than the intrinsic and you want to avoid the haircut.

Comment: Yes, can you update your answer to explain how to calculate the price of the option if you sell it without excising? Apparently you can make much more profits this way. I dont get how to think about this

Comment: And you can imagine any couple dates for the expiry, Aug 15, Dec 15, next week, etc

Comment: @user3180 as you approach the expiration date of the option, the price will approach the value from the formula in this answer. While it's still some time out from expiry, the option price depends on things like implied volatility and the amount of time remaining before expiration. There's no easy formula you can compute in your head. The basics are that the price of an option (both calls and puts) decreases with time if all else stays the same and that the more volatile the market and the stock are, the higher the option price will be.

Answer (score 1):

No one can  answer your question because you did not specify the expiration.  Since Robinhood averages the bid and the ask when providing their data and since I peeked at the option chain, it appears that you're looking at the August $40 call.

The cost of acquiring the stock when buying a call is the strike price plus the cost of the call.  That's $40 plus $7.55 so Robinhood is correct in that the break-even price is $47.55.

To evaluate what an option will be worth at any given time and price prior to expiration, you need an option pricing formula.  You can download one for Excel or you can use a web site [such as this one](http://www.option-price.com/index.php) to calculate it yourself.

Note that future implied volatility of an option is unknown and it will vary between now and expiration.  The IV of your call is very high at about 100.  If it were to drop to 50 in the next few days, your call would lose half of its value.  If it were to drop to 50 halfway until expiration, your call would lose 5/6 of its value.  And obviously, your call would appreciate if IV increased.  Therefore, it's imperative that you understand this component of option pricing.  We've had questions here asking for example, "How come my stock went up 5 points this week and my call lost  money?"  How come? (Hint: Look at the IV).